# Java java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol Save Image File from URL

Tags: java, image, url

I'm looking to save an image from a website URL that ends in a .jpg extension. Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void saveImage(String imageURL){
    Image img = null;
    imageURL = imageURL.substring(2);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageURL);
        img = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Draw the image on to the buffered image
    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    try {
        ImageIO.write(bimage, "jpg", new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/image.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

An example URL is this: i.imgur.com/fq4ZpIEb.jpg.

But, everytime I run this code it returns this error message:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: i.imgur.com/fq4ZpIEb.jpg
```

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: i.imgur.com/fq4ZpIEb.jpg

You need the "http://"

ie:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/akWPX.jpg" would be the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the protocol say `http`, `https` or `ftp` in the image URL